# Alpha list no longer works it multiple names

Tags: categories

I have a theme that worked very well using this code but on Version 4.8.3 its no longer valid.

```
$terms = get_terms( "ingredient", array( 'name__like' => $letter ) );
```

to return all posts where the custom taxonomy ingredient begins with $letter.

The behaviour of name__like was changed in WP 4.8.3 to a text search instead of beginning.

What can I use to achieve the results I had before? Do I need a custom query or ?

Comment: Note that the input should like:  `get_terms( $args )` from version 4.5 (see [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)); What's the generated SQL query? Do you mean it's affected by the [security update](https://wordpress.org/news/2017/10/wordpress-4-8-3-security-release/) in 4.8.3?

Comment: What's your basis to say behavior had changed? Outside of your input being affected by security fix somehow that is unlikely.